# Why do RMSE values increase on a smaller tree (RPART)

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, cart, rpart

AIM: I want to understand why does `RMSE` increase on a smaller tree.

CONTEXT: I am learning the `rpart` algorithm. I had some data, I split it into three sections (training, validation, testing). I am using [this Kaggle dataset.](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques)

I fit the model:

```
homes_model <- rpart(formula = SalePrice ~ ., 
                     data = homes_train, 
                     method = "anova")
```

With this base tree:

[image]

Then, I calculated the RMSE on the test data:

```
pred_base <- predict(object=homes_model,
                newdata = homes_test)

library(Metrics)
rmse_base <- rmse(actual=homes_test$SalePrice, #Actual values
     predicted = pred_base )
```

The `rmse_base` of this first tree is: `46894`.

Then, I looked at the `cptable` to pick the best tree according the lowest `xerror+xstd` rule.

```
    CP nsplit rel error xerror  xstd
1  0.446      0      1.00   1.00 0.096
2  0.114      1      0.55   0.56 0.054
3  0.078      2      0.44   0.48 0.055
4  0.035      3      0.36   0.41 0.037
5  0.021      4      0.33   0.40 0.046
6  0.018      5      0.31   0.41 0.047
7  0.017      6      0.29   0.39 0.045
8  0.017      7      0.27   0.39 0.045
9  0.013      8      0.25   0.37 0.043
10 0.010      9      0.24   0.35 0.043
```

I chose the tree with 7 splits:

```
opt_index <- 7
cp_opt <- homes_model$cptable[opt_index, "CP"]

# Prune the model (to optimized cp value)
homes_model_opt <- prune(tree = homes_model, 
                         cp = cp_opt)
```

I plotted it:

[image]

Then I calculated the `RMSE` again on this smaller tree on testing data:

```
#Computing predicted values 
pred_opt <- predict(object=homes_model_opt,
                newdata = homes_test)

#Compute RMSE
rmse_opt <- rmse(actual=homes_test$SalePrice, #Actual values
     predicted = pred_opt) #Predicted values
```

It went up from `46894` to `49964`. WHY? Shouldn't a smaller tree fit the unseen data better?